# JQuery 1.5 templates: JQuery 1.5 didn't render my template. How do you call JQuery 1.5 templates?

Tags: templates, jquery-1.5

In this code, j correctly becomes an object: j.name, j.addr, j.city, j.state, and j.zip.  However the success function has a JavaScript error of `.tmpl()` isn't a function.

```
<script id="addressTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{tmpl "addressTemplate"}}
    <tr><td>Name: ${name}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Address: ${addr}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>City: ${city}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>State: ${state}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Zip: ${zip}</td></tr>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Home/GetInfo",
            data: {},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (j) {
                $("#addressTemplate").tmpl(j).appendTo("#result");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong to call JQuery 1.5 templates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery templates didn't make it in the core jQuery script. You still need to include jquery.tmpl.js. [Here](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/01/24/jquery-15rc-1-released/#comment-525355) is John Resig's comment.

Comment: This is a good example of why features shouldn't be announced until they are released (or certain).  There are lots of sites claiming templates will be baked in to the jQuery 1.5 core.